# FFmpeg get frames equally spaced out from video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am having some real problems with FFmpeg in my Android application. I am currently trying to take a video recorded from the device and extract frames from the video equally throughout the video. I used this [blog post](http://muzso.hu/2008/12/28/extracting-thumbnails-still-images-frames-from-a-video-with-ffmpeg). The last formula:

`ffmpeg -i input.avi -f image2 -ss 2 -r 0.05 frame-%05d.png`

with my own `-ss` and own `-r` values.

Now everything is fine. Like mentioned in the blog the first 2 frames are the same for some reason. So i delete one of the frames then I feel as though the frames accurately show the video. In the blog it also says to delete some of the last frames I dont do this because then i dont get frames going to the end of the whole video.

> In the output the first two images should be discarded and the next 6 images (from 3rd til 8th) will be the ones we were looking for. Most probably there'll be a 9th image as well which can be discarded too. You can also add the -vframes 8 option (where 8 is number_of_frames + 2) to skip the creation of the last image that you won't need anyway.

How accurately are these frames captured? Because I would like to add timestamps to each frame. (`FFProbe` is not an option because I am using an Android application and dont want to have to build the binaries just for this).

If for example I had a video of 14 seconds long and ffmpeg extracted 11 frames (I remove one of the first duplicate ones, so now 10 frames). If i then did `videoLength / number of frames * which frame I want to find` how accurate would this be? So:

```
14/10 * 1 = 1 so frame one goes from 0s - 1.4s
14/10 * 2 = 2.8 so frame two goes from 1.4s - 2.8s
14/10 * 3 = 4.2 so frame two goes from 2.8s - 4.2s
...
14/10 * 10 = 14 so frame two goes from 12.6s - 14s
```

Would this accurate represent each frame?

If not could someonne give me a better solution please thanks.

The idea is I have created a video cropper with a recyclerview so I will be able to "go over" each frame with a drag tool, calculate how much the frame has been covered and then find what range that frame represents and then set a time for the start and end crop times

Comment: can anybody help please?

Comment: For a constant framerate video, use the fps filter with value `1/(duration/no-of-frames)`

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean would it be possible to write it as an answer please? thanks

Comment: also what do you mean by constant framerate video? please help